# Getting nil from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a storyboard to display my TableViewController, and I'm very new to using storyboards for this, I usually do it all programmatically. So I'm running into some issues. I navigate to the storyboard using the following code:

```
let registerTableViewController = RegisterTableViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(registerTableViewController, animated: true);
```

Simple two-liner, that could my issue, I'm not 100% certain that's how you programmatically move to a storyboard scene, but that's how I've always done it when all my views are laid out programmatically, so let me know if that's the source of the issue.

Now, my tableView has one cell, with the reuse identifier `profileInfoCell`. I've put this into a constant file so I know I'm getting it correctly. Here's my very simple `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Constants.Registration.profileInfoCellIdentifier)

    return cell!
}
```

The problem is that `cell` is being returned nil. Since I'm using a storyboard, I think something is wrong in my setup, which is why I think I may be moving to this scene in the wrong way. If there's any other info you need let me know!

Edit: I am not using static tableView cells. They are prototype cells.

Comment: Can you give screenshot for tableviewcell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil using storyboard static cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131311/dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-returns-nil-using-storyboard-static-cells)

Comment: Which parts of tableviewcell do you want a screenshot for? And @Benoit I've edited my post accordingly, my cells are prototype cells, not static cells, so I do need to dequeue them.

Comment: @BillL You give screenshot of cell with tab identifier of this cell. I think maybe you don't set identifier or some outlet from tableview to controller.

Comment: Missed that, my bad! Retracted my vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are instantiating the view controller wrong.  By creating it like you are, it's totally programmatic and thus bypasses the storyboard entirely

Make sure you need to give the view controller scene an identifier in the Storyboard.

[image]

**Assumptions:**

- Storyboard filename: "Main.storyboard"
- View Controller scene identifier: "RegisterTableViewController"

**Objective-C**

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
RegisterTableViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterTableViewController"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Swift**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main",bundle:nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RegisterTableViewController")
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: OK, again very new with storyboards so bear with me... I'm not familiar with interface builder too well. The storyboard name is the file name, or the storyboard id? And where do I find the view controller identifier? I'm  being told it can't find the storyboard in the bundle.

Comment: I just added a screenshot, to show where you can set the identifier.  Also, just realized I had a typo in my post.  DON'T append ".storyboard" when init'ing the object, just simply reference it by "Main" if it is "Main.storyboard"

Answer (score 1):

You aren't referring to the storyboard when you create your view controller, so none of the configuration in the storyboard scene will be applied.

You need to retrieve the view controller instance from the storyboard using it's scene identifier.  Something like:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main",bundle:nil)
let vc=storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sceneIdentifier")
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You need to set the scene's Storyboard ID in the Interface Builder inspector.  Select the Orange "View Controller" object at the root of the scene and the enter your identifier in the inspector on the right:

[image]

Comment: OK, again very new with storyboards so bear with me... I'm not familiar with interface builder too well. The storyboard name is the file name, or the storyboard id? And where do I find the view controller identifier? I'm  being told it can't find the storyboard in the bundle. (same comment as above)

Answer (score 1):

This is how i achieve

```
override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Constants.Registration.profileInfoCellIdentifier)

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = RegisterTableViewController(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:Constants.Registration.profileInfoCellIdentifier)        
   }

   return cell!
}
```